# why subfloat needs more vertical space?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am doing a test on `subfloat`. I have found that `subfloat` needs more vertical space than `normal` floats. I do not know why. The test code is shown below. Could you help me to remove the additional vertical space in `subfloat` figures?

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{
  A test. balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala 
  balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala 
  balabala. balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala 
  balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala.
}
\end{figure*}

\section{New section}
\lipsum

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\caption{
  A test. balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala 
  balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala 
  balabala. balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala 
  balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala balabala.
}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-10]


\end{document}
```

Parts of the output.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The skip is `farskip` and you can get rid of it with `\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize,farskip=0pt]{subfig}`. The docu claims that it is not inserted at page breaks, but the test doesn't work correctly with `figure*`. Side remark: the showframe package disturbs the test too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The skip is `farskip` and you can get rid of it with

```
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize,farskip=0pt]{sub‌​fig}
```

The package documentation claims that this skip is not inserted at page breaks but this test seems not to work correctly with `figure*`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. do you know how to apply for a single `figure*` environment?